# How to debug an andorid app made with Kivy that crashes when importing pandas?

Tags: python, android, pandas, kivy

I have no problem with pushing a kivy app to my android phone as long as it's very simple.

But when I try to import pandas it just crashes. The app starts loading and then just closes.

Does anyone know what can be the issue and how can I open a debugger or something similar? I know pandas can be imported with Kivy because there are some examples out there using pandas.

Comment: Pandas isn't supported on Android. It might be possible to build it, but it's probably at least a bit tricky.

Comment: is numpy suported?

Comment: Yes....................................

Comment: In case someone has the same issue: I was not able to use numpy at first. When I included `import numpy` in my main file, the Kivy app crashed while loading. I solved this by adding `numpy` to the requirements in the .spec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writing and running a kivy app that uses/imports pandas poses no problem when you run it ordinarily. but when you convert it to an apk, it will load and crash. this is because python4android doesn't support pandas explicitly for now. what you can do is apply a patch.

Comment: is numpy suported?

Comment: numpy have recipe that make her supported you will find recipes in pythonforandroid folder

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a recipe for python for android like the OpenCV recipe. there are many functions in pandas that search in windows/Linux directories. when pandas is installed module data go directly to lib/site-packages but it the not the same case for python-for-android.
to track the issue  try to catch the error of your code and print it in text label like that.

```
try:
 #past your code here
 a=1+1
except Exception as theeror:
 import kivy
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.label import Label 
  
 # Defining a class
 class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
      
    # Function that returns 
    # the root widget
    def build(self):
          
        # Label with text Hello World is 
        # returned as root widget
        return Label(text =str(theeror))          
  
  
 # Here our class is initialized
 # and its run() method is called. 
 # This initializes and starts 
 # our Kivy application.
 MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```